# Parse + React: Render Image From Parse

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, react-native

Using react native I am able to select an image from the camera roll and successfully upload it to Parse. However, I am having trouble retrieving that same image from Parse and rendering it in a new view. I am able to retrieve other fields like so: `this.data.user.phone` but setting the image uri to `this.data.user.image.url()` isn't successful. When I `console.log('this.data.user.image')` I am able to retrieve the image data though.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I think it was just loading the image really slow. `this.data.user.image.url()` seems to work fine.